# How to parse json using sscanf in C?

Tags: c, scanf

I have the following string in the form of json:

{"num":1,"data":{"city":"delhi"}}

I need to get the value of "num" key using `sscanf`. Here is my attempt. I know it's incorrect. But I don't know how to do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    char *str = "{\"num\":1,\"data\":{\"city\":\"delhi\"}}";
    char *ret = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);

    sscanf(str, "{\"num\":%s, %s" , ret);

    printf("%s", ret);
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use sscanf. JSON is too complex for that. Use a proper JSON parser instead.

Comment: There are two possibilities: use a dirty hack, if you are sure, that the string is exactly formatted this way `int num = atoi(strchr(str, ':')+1);` or use a json parser, if the string can vary.

Comment: @OliverMason, I have no other option than sscanf and regex. My entire implementation is in C. I can't even use third party plugins, libraries etc.

Comment: @Ctx, I think your approach would work, since my string has a fixed format. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Using sscanf for this is a terrible idea. Here's a very lightweight JSON parser written entirely in ANSI (portable) C. You can just drop it into your project: https://github.com/udp/json-parser

Comment: cJSON is another simple drop in parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> sscanf(str, "{\"num\":%s, %s" , ret);
> ```

is wrong, first you have two "%s" but you give only one location to save string (*ret*), and it does not extract as you expect

you want

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    char *str = "{\"num\":1,\"data\":{\"city\":\"delhi\"}}";
    char *ret = malloc(10); /* by definition sizeof(char) is 1 */

    if (sscanf(str, "{\"num\":%9[^,]" , ret) == 1)
        printf("value is '%s'\n", ret);

    free(ret);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution

```
/tmp % gcc -Wall p.c
/tmp % ./a.out
value is '1'
/tmp %
```

but to use *scanf* to parse is limited

Comment: Just what I wanted. Thank you so much. I am using sscanf because my json is of fixed length and fixed format. So, this would work.

Comment: @no_one so fine. When you read/extract using one of the *scanf* function I recommend you to always check the return value to know how much elements was got, and when it is a string to limit the length where *scanf* will write (here 9 even the string is sized 10 because the ending null character is not count even written)